# Does Codeigniter's validation class support multiple forms on the same page?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Can anyone confirm that Codeigniter's validation class doesn't support multiple forms on the same page, especially when the forms share 'name' fields?

That seems to be the case from the posts I've read, just wondering if it is -- and if there are any ingenious workarounds? Much thanks.

Comment: I should clarify, the validation works. It's the error reporting that's the issue as multiple instances of the same error are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, interesting issue.  There's no way to derive directly from POST data which form submitted that information.  Unless you "namespace" the field names, you're probably out of luck with multiple validated forms on the same page.

Another approach might be to store a hidden field specific to that form, and extend the Form_validation class to show errors related to that form only.

However, it would be *much* easier just to rename/namespace your fields.  Probably more sustainable too.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. A compromise I was considering was just to simply display <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> once at the top of the page, but again that wouldn't help with overlapping name fields so you're idea is a good approach.